# Clarification on the witch, known spells, patron spells and bonus spells per level

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class-feature, witch

I've played Pathfinder for a few sessions earlier but only with spontaneous casters or melee strikers and only at lower levels.

Now we're running a high-level campaign (starting level 12) and I've decided to play a witch, specifically the scarred witch doctor archetype (SWD from here on). I've talked to my GM and he's allowed me to use old version of the SWD which uses Constitution as its casting stat for all purposes. This also means that I will be playing an orc.

Now, I think I've managed to get a grasp on how prepared casters work, and specifically the witch, but there are some things that I would like some clarification on regarding ability scores, spells known, bonus spells per day and the witch's patron spells. I hope this isn't too broad, I'll try to keep the questions separated and well explained.

#### Spells known

As I understand it, spells known start at "all level 0 spells and 3+Int mod (CON in my case) level one spells" that my familiar will know. Then at each level two more spells are learnt from the witch spell list. Do you also get the +Int modifier bonus at each level?

The orc race has the favoured class bonus: "Add one spell from the witch spell list to the witch's familiar. This spell must be at least one level below the highest spell level the witch can cast."

Do I understand it correctly if I then add 2 + 1 (favoured class) per level of witch where I choose that favoured class bonus?

I also assume that spells known is not affected by the ability score I have at level 12, but at level 1.

#### Bonus spells per day

Does the bonus spells per day table work in the same way? Where I get bonus spells per day per level with the increased ability score or is the bonus spells per day fixed by the ability score modifier at the level I am at?

#### Patron spells

Are patron spells completely separate from the other spells known and therefore not included in the 2 +1 spells known per level?

#### TLDR

1. Is spells known affected by ability score modifier per level?
2. Is favoured class that grants +1 spell per level increasing the base spells learnt per level to 3?
3. Is bonus spells per day affected by ability score at different levels or only at the current level?
4. Are patron spells completely separate from spells known per level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Is spells known affected by ability score modifier per level?

No, they are not, not for prepared or spontaneous casters. The only time ability scores come into play is with the starting spellbook/familiar for 1st-level wizards, witches, and the like. And yes, that uses the character’s Intelligence (or Constitution in your case) at the time the first level of wizard or witch or whatever is taken, and you do not retroactively gain new 1st-level spells when your Intelligence (Constitution) goes up.

Note that prepared spellcasters with a spellbook/familiar can also just buy additional spells known. They are not limited by their class features the way spontaneous spellcasters are (spontaneous casters *can* buy *pages of spell knowledge* but those are very expensive).

> 2. Is favoured class that grants +1 spell per level increasing the base spells learnt per level to 3?

Yes, it is. You understand this correctly. That sort of favored class bonus is far more valuable for spontaneous spellcasters; you may actually prefer hp or skill points. Also, since you must select spells of a level below the highest you can cast, and you start with all cantrips already available to you, this favored class bonus cannot be used until 3rd level, when you get 2nd-level spells and can thus choose 1st-level spells with this feature.

> 3. Is bonus spells per day affected by ability score at different levels or only at the current level?

Your ability score as it is at the time you prepare spells each day. Some fleeting temporary bonuses or penalties don’t count, but other than that, you just determine your bonus spells each time you prepare spells based on your Intelligence (Constitution) at the time.

> 4. Are patron spells completely separate from spells known per level?

Yes, they are, they do not count towards those you learn normally.

Comment: "you do not retroactively gain new 1st-level spells when your Intelligence (Constitution) goes up" Do you have a source for this? IIRC, there was a comment about how the opposite is true

Comment: Note, for #2, it's not quite "goes up to 3 spells learnt per level" since the bonus spell from favored class "must be at least one level below the highest spell level the witch can cast". So this is a wasted FCB until 3rd level when you get access to 2nd level spells (as a witch). Since before then you wouldn't be able to choose 1st level spells and you already know all 0-level spells. So it's "2 spells of any level + 1 at least 1 level below the highest spell level you can cast"

Comment: It looks like there is [at least some debate](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rd14?Retroactive-bonus-Formulae-from-Intelligence) over this point. And there is a [RPGSE answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58772/does-a-permanent-enhancement-bonus-to-intelligence-increase-1st-level-spells-kno) that indicates the opposite.

Comment: @JaredGoguen It says you “begin play” with that many. This is a singular, one-time event, not a continuing statement about the state of your spellbook/familiar. Unless or until someone can show me something from Paizo on the subject, that is in my mind the final word on the subject and everyone arguing otherwise is grasping at straws. That answer is wrong and I have downvoted it.

Comment: @Simple Lime Yes I understood that bit but decided to simplify the question a bit, the one lower spell implied, sorry for any confusion. :)

Comment: Yeah I figured, just wanted to make sure everyone was on the same page, it's not just us that's going to be using this question for reference and the next people to come along might have missed that and it is a very important distinction

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will upvote and accept as soon as I reach enough reputation :)