# Do Pathfinder Witches have a dedicated Patron spell slot?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, witch, spell-slots

In Pathfinder, do Witches have a Patron spell slot?

APG pg 70, under "Patron Spells" says:

> At 2nd level, and every two levels thereafter, a witch's patron adds new spells to a witch's list of spells known. These spells are also automatically added to the list of spells stored by the familiar.

pg 69, under "Witch's Familiar", at "Store Spells", states:

> Starting at 1st level, a witch's familiar stores all of the spells that the witch knows. This does not allow the familiar to cast these spells or use spell-trigger or spell completion magic items. Starting at 2nd level, and every two levels thereafter, a witch's familiar adds new bonus spells to the witch's spell list based on her patron.

The first quote, from pg 70 states twice that the witch learns the spell - it is both "add[ed] to [the] list of spells known" and "added to the list of spells stored by the familiar", while pg 69 seems to state that spells stored by the familiar *are* the spells known.

pg 65, under "Class Features", then "Spells" states:

> A witch can cast only a certain number of spells of each spell level per day. Her base daily spell allotment is given on Table 2-10. In addition, she receives bonus spells per day if she has a high Intelligence score (see Table 1-3 of the Pathfinder RPG Core Rulebook).

This is weak evidence though, as pg 39 of the CRB states much the same - no mention of domain slots, which are listed on pg 40-41 of the CRB:

> A cleric gains one domain spell slot for each level of cleric spell she can cast, from 1st on up. Each day, a cleric can prepare one of the spells from her two domains in that slot. If a domain spell is not on the cleric spell list, a cleric can prepare it only in her domain spell slot. Domain spells cannot be used to cast and spells spontaneously.

There appears to be no evidence that Witches have a special patron (analogous to domain) spell slot. However, the Witch "Prepared Spells" page from Dyslexic Character Sheets clearly shows a patron spell slot with a "+1" by it, and "Spellcasting for Pathfinder Autosheet v6" lists it as a standard "Bonus Spells" option.

Note that I am *not* asking about spell slot levels occupied by patron spells, as in these questions:

- https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pbr4?Spell-levels-for-winter-patron-witches
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/299539/witch_patron_spell_slots/
- [Clarification on the witch, known spells, patron spells and bonus spells per level](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105734/2293) (TLDR point 4  is *close*, but specifies spells *known*, and the answer appropriately confines itself to the question).

Comment: Welcome to this stack! Take the [tour]. In a case like this—you've a question, a lot of evidence supporting an answer, and looking mainly for confirmation—, it's totally legit to ask the question at its most basic but omit from your question the bulk of your research then answer the question yourself using your research. That way you can score rep for the question and answer. It's cool, though, if you want to do a mess of research and leave that in your question, too. Just presenting an alternative. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: In this case I was genuinely worried that I'd missed something - my arguments were insufficient to persuade half the table (oddly, I'm the one playing the Witch which'd be weakened). Thanks for your advice - certainly the down/upvote system might have resulted in similar confirmation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## A [witch](http://legacy.aonprd.com/advancedPlayersGuide/baseClasses/witch.html) receives witch spell slots according to the Table: Witch supplemented by bonus spells slots for a high ability score

A typical witch does *not* get, for example, an additional spell slot at each level that can only be used for preparing a spell granted by the witch's patron.

Further, *neither* having a spell as a spell known *nor* being able to prepare a spell because that spell is available through a particular source *grants* a witch an *additional* spell slot with which to cast that spell.

Were a witch to receive extra spell slots above and beyond those listed on the Table: Witch, this would be made clear in the text, and, I suspect, also on the table, probably in much the same way the [cleric](http://legacy.aonprd.com/coreRulebook/classes/cleric.html#cleric) class description makes it clear in its [text](http://legacy.aonprd.com/coreRulebook/classes/cleric.html#cleric) and on its table.

While in some campaigns it may be reasonable to grant a witch a patron spell slot at each level like a cleric gains a domain spell slot, that's a house rule, and one that this GM would try to avoid making. Casting spells is already the most powerful ability in the game, and making more spells per day available to what's already one of the game's most powerful casters doesn't seem like a good idea to this GM. However, if the other PCs are, like, a wizard, cleric, and an arcanist, it's possible a witch may feel slightly behind, and such a house rule could alleviate that issue.

In short, you're correct that there is no evidence supporting the existence of a witch receiving "patron spell slots." I don't know why Dyslexic Character Sheets and Autosheet aren't following the rules; that's something to take up with the developers of those products.